# how to set checkedlistbox check ture only for data present in dataset C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

vs 2008 - C#

I am having a problem with checkedlistbox, can anyone help me, or give me some idea what should i do to fix this thing..

I have a Checkedlistbox with jobs in it.
I want to check the jobs assigned to employees from dataset and check only those jobs true..
The problem is when it checks the 1st Job true,
it comes out of foreach loop and throws exception.
"List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change."
This is the code i have written,

```
string sSQL="select JOBNO from RentalVehicle";
dataset ds = munshi.executeDS(sSQL,"Jobs").Tables["Jobs"];

foreach(DataRow Erow in ds.Rows)    
{
    int CLB_RowNo = 0;

    //Jobdetail(2010-0191, HWS-01, ISB-6,KAD2-2, MAINT-01, PMO-2011-0052)
    string[] JNos = Erow["JOBNO"].ToString().Split(', ');   

    string SelectedJob = "", AJob = "";

    // Looping CLB_JobNo(CheckedListBox)
    foreach (Object obj in CLB_JobNo.Items) 
    {
        int i = 0;
        SelectedJob = obj.ToString();
        foreach (string part in JNos)
        {
            AJob = JNos[i].ToString();
            if (SelectedJob == AJob)
            {
                CLB_JobNo.SetItemChecked(CLB_RowNo, true);
            }
            i++;
        }
        CLB_RowNo++;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `foreach` loop, try a `for` loop and modify the collection based on the index

Comment: @Habib Thanks alot man, u solved my problem. Your tiny post was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of items first and then iterate though it.

```
 Object[] jobs = CLB_JobNo.Items.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
 foreach (Object obj in jobs)
 {
     SelectedJob = obj.ToString();
     if (JNos.Contains(SelectedJob))
     {
         CLB_JobNo.SetItemChecked(CLB_RowNo, true);
     }
     CLB_RowNo++;
 }
```